# .htaccess code giving error 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this code that transform domain.com/Birthdays/birthdays.php?n=Something into domain.com/Birthdays/Something and also take off the .php and .html for other pages:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Birthday/(\w+)$ /Birthdays/birthdays.php?n=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

The problem comes when I add this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Birthdays/(.*)$ [L]
RewriteRule ^Birthday/(\w+)$ /Birthdays/birthdays.php?n=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

It gives me an error (500) but if I change the (.*) to (\w+) it works. But I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^Birthday/(\w*)$ /Birthdays/birthdays.php?n=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You are getting 500 due to **looping error** as your rules's pattern is matching starting and rewritten URI.